# Adobe Flash Action Script 3.0 T Test Function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash

I am trying to write a function in Flash so that when given two columns of values and click the button "T-test", it can give the result of the t-test.

```
A        B
0.3      0.5
0.5      0.6
0.66     0.56

T-test
```

Could you please help me out with this?

Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any information about *what* `T-test` is, but a function to compare two collections of numbers might look like:

```
function compare(columnA:Vector.<Number>, columnB:Vector.<Number>):Number
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < columnA.length; i++)
    {
        var a:Number = columnA[i];
        var b:Number = columnB[i];

        // Compare a to b.
    }

    return 1;
}


compare(
    new <Number>[0.3, 0.5, 0.66],
    new <Number>[05, 0.6, 0.56]
);
```

Comment: I was trying to do independent two sample t-test, i.e. Student's t-test. The first column is a list of buttons, which have values as its label. The second column is a list of text field, and the values were filled in by clicking other buttons.Thank you very much!